# Plotting confidence intervals data with R

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

I would like to plot mean CPUE by year and add in CIs that are already calculated.

The CIs are calculated following an approach for trawl survey data so I do not think I can use any of the CI plot functions available in R. I would really appreciate any help.

I have been trying to figure this out following examples I found online, but the CIs are not being plotted on my data points. I have R version 3.1.0 on windows 8. This is my code.

```
dput(fall)

structure(list(Year = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"), class = "factor"), 
    Season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fall", 
    "Spring"), class = "factor"), CPUE = c(2.67597320766895, 
    1.13720423803133, 3.33880765324431, 0.806172684858967, 1.4489759307485, 
    10.5492990950043, 4.52479039663784), Variance = c(6.80824504958873, 
    0.320707030421567, 11.5769406857122, 1.05791053306542, 0.187046436602381, 
    15.8421823978692, 2.68384838783695), SD = c(2.60926139924476, 
    0.566310012644635, 3.40249036526369, 1.0285477786984, 0.432488654882855, 
    3.98022391303168, 1.63824552123207), Number = c(75, 91, 87, 
    85, 115, 157, 208), CV = c(0.975070076100538, 0.497984437364567, 
    1.01907348929115, 1.27584052153583, 0.298478839920718, 0.377297475139038, 
    0.362059980159386), lower = c(2.07563668109912, 1.01926446969017, 
    2.61363856286983, 0.584320068914576, 1.36908295705723, 9.92183627713643, 
    4.30084507885747), upper = c(3.27630973423878, 1.2551440063725, 
    4.06397674361879, 1.02802530080336, 1.52886890443977, 11.1767619128722, 
    4.7487357144182)), .Names = c("Year", "Season", "CPUE", "Variance", 
"SD", "Number", "CV", "lower", "upper"), row.names = c(NA, 7L
), class = "data.frame")
```

My plot attempt was:

```
plot(fall$CPUE, type='n', xlab="Year", ylab='Mean CPUE', axes=F)
axis(1, at=1:8, labels=levels(fall$Year))
axis(2)
box()
lines(fall$Year, fall$CPUE, col=1)
points(fall$Year, fall$CPUE, col=1, pch=16)
arrows(y0 = fall$lower, y1 = fall$upper, x0 = fall$CPUE, x1 = fall$CPUE, 
length=0.1, code = 3, col = 4, angle = 90)
```

Comment: Have you tried the plotrix package? See here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64880/software-to-produce-confidence-interval-error-bars-from-summary-statistics-witho/64889#64889

Comment: Thank you - using plotCI in the plotrix package worked.

Comment: You are welcome. You can post your own answer to this question. This is normal on Stack Overflow (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Post the code and a picture with the result you got so you can help future readers. It would be nice if you give credits to my answer on Cross Validated SE on your answer here. Let me know if you need help to upload the picture. Tks.

Comment: Hi - yes if you can work me through how to upload the picture that would be great and thank you for your answer on the Cross Validation SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andre's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64880/software-to-produce-confidence-interval-error-bars-from-summary-statistics-witho/64889#64889) helped me to find a solution.

Data for plot

```
structure(list(CPUE = c(2.67597320766895, 1.13720423803133, 3.33880765324431, 0.806172684858967, 1.4489759307485, 10.5492990950043, 4.52479039663784 ), lower = c(2.25499288520513, 1.04583532734779, 2.80755247046762, 0.640225963050555, 1.37919786502951, 9.90712658332295, 4.26047455308042 ), upper = c(3.09695353013276, 1.22857314871488, 3.870062836021, 0.972119406667378, 1.51875399646749, 11.1914716066857, 4.78910624019525 )), .Names = c("CPUE", "lower", "upper"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))
```

Plot

```
plot(fall$CPUE, type='l', xlab="Year", ylab='Mean CPUE', axes=F,ylim=c(0,12)) 
axis(1, at=1:8, labels=levels(fall$Year)) 
axis(2) 
box() 

require(plotrix)

plotCI(fall$CPUE,y=NULL,uiw = fall$upper-fall$CPUE,ui=NULL,li=NULL,err="y", sfrac=0.01,gap=0,slty=par("lty"),add=T,scol="black",pch=18,pt.bg=par("bg"))
```

[image]